# Display hierarchical list terms as checkboxes

Tags: php, wordpress, filtering, custom-taxonomy, wp-list-categories

I am trying to convert a list of hierarchical terms in to checkboxes. The terms are being generated using the code below, but by default they are displayed as links.

```
<?php 
//list terms in a given taxonomy using wp_list_categories (also useful as a widget if using a PHP Code plugin)

$taxonomy     = 'tags';
$orderby      = 'name'; 
$show_count   = 1;      // 1 for yes, 0 for no
$pad_counts   = 0;      // 1 for yes, 0 for no
$hierarchical = 1;      // 1 for yes, 0 for no
$title        = '';

$args = array(
  'taxonomy'     => $taxonomy,
  'orderby'      => $orderby,
  'show_count'   => $show_count,
  'pad_counts'   => $pad_counts,
  'hierarchical' => $hierarchical,
  'title_li'     => $title
);

?>

<ul class="categories">
    <?php wp_list_categories( $args ); ?>
</ul>
```

Here is the HTML that `<?php wp_list_categories( $args ); ?>` outputs...

```
<ul class="categories">
<li class="cat-item cat-item-21"><a href="http://tandsdev.co.uk/portfoliotags/client/" >Client</a>      (0)
<ul class='children'>
<li class="cat-item cat-item-22"><a href="http://tandsdev.co.uk/portfoliotags/bmw/" >BMW</a> (3)
</li>
</ul>
</li>
<li class="cat-item cat-item-25"><a href="http://tandsdev.co.uk/portfoliotags/section/" >Section</a>    (0)
<ul class='children'>
<li class="cat-item cat-item-27"><a href="http://tandsdev.co.uk/portfoliotags/automotive/" >Automotive</a> (3)
</li>
<li class="cat-item cat-item-28"><a href="http://tandsdev.co.uk/portfoliotags/property/" >Property</a> (2)
</li>
</ul>
</li>
<li class="cat-item cat-item-26"><a href="http://tandsdev.co.uk/portfoliotags/service/" >Service</a> (0)
<ul class='children'>
<li class="cat-item cat-item-29"><a href="http://tandsdev.co.uk/portfoliotags/branding/" >Branding</a> (3)
</li>
<li class="cat-item cat-item-30"><a href="http://tandsdev.co.uk/portfoliotags/email/" >Email</a> (3)
</li>
<li class="cat-item cat-item-31"><a href="http://tandsdev.co.uk/portfoliotags/website/" >Website</a> (2)
</li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

The checkbox code I would like each term to be displayed as will form a filtering system which can be seen here http://jsfiddle.net/amesy/kwqpf5fv/6/

```
<div class="tags">
    <h3>service</h3>
        <label><input type="checkbox" id="type-Website" rel="Website">Website</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" id="type-Email" rel="Email">Email</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" id="type-Branding" rel="Branding">Branding</label>
    <h3>sector</h3>
        <label><input type="checkbox" id="type-Automotive" rel="Automotive">Automotive</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" id="type-Property" rel="Property">Property</label>
</div>
```

I would still like to keep the checkboxes hierarchical as in the example above, but the titles in the h3 tags are parent terms and I do not want these as checkboxes, how do I do all this? :)

Comment: Can you display the html that the <?php wp_list_categories( $args ); ?> prints out so I can be specific with code examples?

Comment: i've just added the html above, thanks

Comment: Are you incontroll of the category names if not, you may need to replace them.

Comment: The category names are parent terms which are added via the custom post tags in WordPress. So yes i'm in control and they are dynamic.

Comment: Since this is WordPress you might want to create a custom function that replaces the wp_list_categories and call that instead which generates your desired output.

Comment: that sounds like the best plan but I don't know how to write that function, maybe i should edit this post or repost requesting such a function.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68238/discussion-between-demodave-and-amesey).

Answer (score 1):

Try add this class in your functions setup.

```
// Keep Categories ordered by group on backend
if ( ! class_exists( 'ftChangeTaxonomyCheckboxlistOrder' ) ){

    class ftChangeTaxonomyCheckboxlistOrder {   

        function ftChangeTaxonomyCheckboxlistOrder(){

            function changeTaxonomyCheckboxlistOrder( $args, $post_id)
            {
                if ( isset( $args['taxonomy']))
                    $args['checked_ontop'] = false;
                return $args;
            }

            add_filter('wp_terms_checklist_args','changeTaxonomyCheckboxlistOrder',10,2);
        }

    } // class ends here

    $fttaxonomychangeorder = new ftChangeTaxonomyCheckboxlistOrder();

}// top most if condition ends here
```

Answer (score 0):

Typically, the data would be stored in a tree model, such as the [Nested Set Model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model), which is then iterated over, sometimes recursively, to display results.

A helpful example is [PHP File Tree](http://www.abeautifulsite.net/php-file-tree/), by Cora LaViska, but of course you would need to modify it to output the desired HTML.

If your data is only ever one level deep, then you could alternately create a 3-dimensional array:

```
// Please note that this is just an example that you will have to adapt to your specific needs
$nodes = array();
// add each title:
$nodes['title1'] = array();

// add each node to the corresponding title:
// you will need to add 'id', 'rel', and probably 'label' for the checkbox output
$nodes['title1'][] = array(
  'taxonomy'     => $taxonomy,
  'orderby'      => $orderby,
  'show_count'   => $show_count,
  'pad_counts'   => $pad_counts,
  'hierarchical' => $hierarchical,
  'title_li'     => $title
);

// then iterate through them and display
foreach($nodes AS $title=>$node) {
  echo "<h3>$title</h3>";
  // and finally iterate through the child nodes to display your checkboxes:
  foreach($node AS $child) {
    // assuming you added the appropriate fields
    echo '<label><input type="checkbox" id="' . $child['id'] . '" rel="' . $child['rel'] . '">' . $child['label'] . '</label>';
  }
}
```